# It is about wow slider installation in Joomla 3.6.2

Tags: joomla3.0

Am trying to install wow slider in my joomla 3.6.2 site in localhost but I got an error which state "Unable to find install package" please help me

Answer (score 0):

Some common reasons for this error:

1. The version you are trying to install is intended for a different version of Joomla (e.g. you are trying to install a Joomla 2.5 extension in Joomla 3.x).
2. The ZIP (or other type of archive) file might have a collection of extensions inside and needs to be expanded first before you can install the relevant extension. Typically these archive files will have "UNZIP-FIRST" or similar in the file name.
3. You have incorrect file permissions on the `/tmp` folder so the archive file cannot be uploaded
4. The size of the archive file is greater than the `upload_max_filesize` and/or the `post_max_size` PHP settings.
5. There is insufficient space to upload the file.